# Without event triggering how to close the window

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I am currrently using gtkmm package with eclipse ide in linux system. I am doing gui programming now. I have to close one gui window without any event triggering when my timer is elapsed. Please help me. Thanx in advance

Comment: try the C++/Gtkmm equivalent of gtk_widget_destroy () or gtk_window_close ()

Comment: Hi thanks your reply. I have tried that. but basically in gtkmm gui things will work with event triggering only but my case i need to modify a gui without any event triggering if no response from the gui in particular time.

Comment: You just neef to hold a reference to the window that you want to close, then on the timer trigger method use the above methods on the window reference.

Comment: "timer elapsing" can be an event of course... With Gtk+ the typical choice is [g_timeout_add_seconds()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds) or g_timeout_add(). Without you showing code we really can't tell what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. It is working fine.